# When two cells A and B are in the same row, and cell A moves to a different row, is there a function to move cell B to the same row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I use a Google Sheets for our club's attendance. The sheet is linked to another Google Form so a list of names can automatically be created and sorted alphabetically. In this sheet I also manually enter points next to peoples' names based on activities we do.

The problem is that since the list of names grows over time, the row positions of each person's name changes, but the point values I have manually entered do not move, so I have to adjust the rows each value is in so they are matched with the correct names again.

I was wondering if there is a function using array formula so these point values stay in the same row as the row of each name changes, and assuming no names are deleted.

So far I have not been able to find a function that locks the values to the names when the names list dynamically updates.

Solutions that I have thought of but not tried yet include:

- Having points entered manually on another sheet next to a static set of names, and importing the points to the correct name after comparing the list of names in both sheets.
- Having points next to a static set of names somewhere else in the sheet, and placing the point values next to the correct name in the list after comparing the names in the dynamic set against the static set.

Comment: Think of sharing a spreadsheet with dummy data that illustrates your situation, which shows what you you have tried so far and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

From a spreadsheet perspective, there is no relationship between the column populated with a formula and the column with manual point entries.  You need to create a relationship between the two columns.

As you suggested in the latter part of you inquiry, I would recommend having a static names "database" where you assign point values to the respective person.  Then use a VFORMULA or XFORMULA to find the points associated with each person.

Another thing you can do is highlight names that are NOT in the database with a conditional formatting formula, if necessary, to help you keep track of new names that get added to the list. This will help make sure that everyone is accounted for as the list grows.